# Setting form to display onclick disappears on page refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, onclick

I have a form that I would like to show on click of an href. I've managed to get this working but the page refreshes and it goes back to display none. Pretty sure there is something I can do in the PHP perhaps to make this permanent.
This codeblock outputs the form and also does a database query when someone clicks 'edit category' on a category table.

```
<!-- Form to edit category -->

<form id="edit-cat-form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="edit_cat">Edit Category</label>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
       $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
       $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = $cat_id ";
       $edit_cat_query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_cat_query)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
         }
     } ?>

     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title" value="<?php if(isset($cat_title)) 
      {echo $cat_title;} ?>">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
</div>
</div> 
</form>
```

The following code displays the categories and edit/delete category options through a db query which I haven't included just to lessen code pasted here

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
   $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
   $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

   echo "<tr>"
       ."<td>{$cat_id}</td>"
       ."<td>{$cat_title}</td>"
       ."<td><a href='categories.php?delete={$cat_id}'>Delete</a>"
       ." | "
       ."<a href='categories.php?edit={$cat_id}' onclick='displayForm()'>Edit</a></td>"
       ."</tr>";
}
```

So with the code as it is, the form to edit the category is displaying and when the 'edit' option is clicked, the category title appears as the value input.

But I'd prefer to make the form completely invisible until the edit option is selected.

So here is the css & javascript I've used

```
<style>
#edit-cat-form {
  display:none;
}
</style>

<script>
// Show edit category form on 'edit' click
 function displayForm() {
      document.getElementById('edit-cat-form').style.display = 'block';
 }
</script>
```

As mentioned this works for a brief moment before the page finishes refreshing. I've tried setting the header location but has no effect.

Any ideas on how I can make this stick would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to solve this would just be to make it so that PHP doesn't render any part of the form unless the "edit" parameter is set in the URL:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
?>
  <form id="edit-cat-form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="edit_cat">Edit Category</label>

      <?php
       $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
       $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = $cat_id ";
       $edit_cat_query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_cat_query)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
         }
       ?>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title" value="<?php if(isset($cat_title)) 
        {echo $cat_title;} ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </form>
<?php }  ?>
```

and get rid of the

```
#edit-cat-form {
  display:none;
}
```

CSS, and also remove the whole `displayForm()` JavaScript function.

(P.S. You could do something a bit slicker than this where it loads the form via AJAX instead without a full page refresh, but that's more involved and needs a lot more changes. Maybe someone else will write that option as another answer.)

Comment: Nice, thanks. It ends up being the exact same functionality. I can't believe I didn't just do/think of that, to begin with. Doh. I'll mark it as resolved. Cheers.